# Umbraco CMS login failed

Tags: .net, authentication, umbraco, umbraco8

i am working on one of my project and suddenly my umbraco cms is showing

*Login Failed for User*
I dont know why this is happening i tried serval ways but nothing is working , can anyone help me or has faced same kind issue .
if i missed any information to put please comment i will add that .
Please help.[image]

Comment: did you check the Umbraco log to see if the connection to the database is working as per expectations?

Comment: connect to the database and check if the user is locked or no, there are 2 possible problems - database connection issue or user is locked

Comment: the user is locked but what do i do to resolve that issue

Answer (score 0):

If your connection to the website's database is working correctly and if you have set up the SMTP details correctly you can do reset password as well.

If you don't see a link of reset password on the login screen of Umbraco back office than you need to update the `<allowPasswordReset>true</allowPasswordReset>` in  /config/umbracoSettings.config file